# How do I use PinTool to find the offset from an address stored in a register?

Tags: c++11, memory, trace

This might be very easy but I'm new to pintool. Basically, my question is: for an instruction such as:

```
mov 0x28(%rax) %xmm1
```

How do I record the value 0x28 into the output trace file? Is it the difference between IARG_MEMORYREAD_EA and IARG_REG_VALUE?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check, if 0x28 is overwritten or stays the same?
In Assambler it does not change the value in the register at all.
So you could just use 0x28 again to do what ever.